# Proving that only two points of intersection are sufficient for an accumulation point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

My analysis textbook defines accumulation points as follows:

Let $E$ be a set of real numbers. Any point $x$ (not necessarily in $E$) is an accumulation point of $E$ if for every $c>0$ the intersection $(x-c, x+c)\cap E $ contains infinitely many points.

Then an exercise asks : Show that $x$ is an accumulation point of $E$ if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$ there are at least two points belonging to the set $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\cap E$.

My problem is in proving the implication that if there are at least two points of intersection between $E$ and any $\epsilon$ neighbourhood of $x$ then there are infinitely many such points of intersection, as stated by the definition.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you should ask why the "at least two points" can not be replaced by "at least one point". The essentially idea is that every neighborhood of $x$ should contain at least one point of $E$ different from $x$ and by choosing smaller and smaller neighborhoods we can see that any specific neighborhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $E$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that for every $\epsilon>0$, there are at least two, but not infinitely many, points in $F_\epsilon:=(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\cap E$. Since $F_\epsilon$ is finite, there is a $y\in F_\epsilon$ which is closest to $x$ but is not $x$. Thus $F_{|x-y|}\subset\{x\}$, which contradicts that this have at least two elements.

Answer (score 0):

The "point" is that at least one of the (at least) two points in $E\cap (x-e,x+e)$ is not $x.$ So every nbhd of $x$ contains $y\in E$ with $y\ne x.$

Version 1 : Take $y_1\ne x$ with $y_1\in E\cap (x-1,x+1) .$ Take $y_{n+1}\ne x$ with $$y_{n+1}\in E\cap (x-|x-y_n|/2, x+|x-y_n|/2).$$ By induction on $n$ we have $0<|x-y_n|<2^{-n}$ and $y_{n+1}\not \in \{y_j :j\leq n\}.$  So $i\ne j\implies y_i\ne y_j$. Hence the set $\{y_j:j\geq n\}$ is infinite for each $n\in N.$

For any $e>0$ take any $n\in N$ large enough that $2^{-n}<e.$ Then $E\cap (x-e,x+e)\supset \{y_j: j\geq n\}.$

Version 2: A smoother way to do this is to note that "Every nbhd of $x$ contains  $y\in E$ with $y\ne x$" is equivalent to $x\in Cl (E\backslash \{x\}).$ Then $x$ cannot have a nbhd $U$ such that $S=U\cap (E\backslash \{x\})$ is finite... Because then $S$ is closed, so $U\backslash S$ is a nbhd of $x$ which is   disjoint from $E\backslash \{x\},$ contrary to $x\in Cl (E\backslash \{x\}).$